# May I rely on the uniqueness of enum option values throughout a project?

Tags: c#

I am writing an application that uses multiple sub classes with a field of the following definition:

```
public _ACTION ACTION { get; set; }
public enum _ACTION { INVALID, UPDATE, VALID }
```

Depending on the value provided in that field an action is taken later on. While only the first class was implemented, the corresponding piece of code looked like this:

```
switch (action) {
    case Class1._ACTION.INVALID:
        this.ColorRow(row, StyleNotOK);
        break;
    case Class1._ACTION.UPDATE:
        this.ColorRow(row, StyleUpdate);
        break;
    case Class1._ACTION.VALID:
        break;
}
```

With the advent of the second class (Class2) extending the same base class as Class1 (and every class after that), the switch would have gotten more complicated, and I thought about doing the switch statement like this:

```
switch (action) {
    case Class1._ACTION.INVALID:
    case Class2._ACTION.INVALID:
        this.ColorRow(row, StyleNotOK);
        break;
    case Class1._ACTION.UPDATE:
    case Class2._ACTION.UPDATE:
        this.ColorRow(row, StyleUpdate);
        break;
    case Class1._ACTION.VALID:
    case Class2._ACTION.VALID:
        break;
}
```

However, the way I understand it is that a distinct enum option is represented by a value. If the values representing the enum options would be used twice, that switch could fail.

A solution is appearant, use a base class to define the enum, however, I am interested in the internals of the implementation. Can you generally rely on the uniqueness of the values representing the enum options?

Comment: Why are you defining the Enum inside a class? Why not just define it standalone in your namespace and use it everywhere? So instead of Class1 and Class2 having an own Enum each you'd just have one central Enum thus you wouldn't need to change the switch statement no matter how many classes

Comment: If `Class2` inherits from `Class1`, `Class1._ACTION.INVALID` and `Class2._ACTION.INVALID` refer to exactly the same value of exactly the same type. The check is redundant. Consider moving your enum outside the class; nested enums may look "organized" but are more confusing than necessary, especially when the type is `public`. (As a bonus, this allows you to declare `public Action Action { get; set; }`, which is not allowed if `Action` is a nested type.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I updated the information in the post. Both Class1 and Class2 inherit the same base class.

Comment: It's just an enum, though. Why would you bother differentiating it between classes? Especially if it's all inherited from the same thing. Just split it off and make it globally usable without any connection to these classes.

Comment: If `Class1._ACTION` and `Class2._ACTION` are *not* the same type, the switch as you wrote it isn't legal in the first place: tags of different enums are incomparable without casting them, even if they happen to have the same name or value. You would need awkward casting to and from `int` to even compare them. If you need extensibility and are not willing or able to do that in a shared type, consider *not* using an enum but something more flexible, like a virtual method (and/or new behavior classes with that implement `Action` that you keep single instances of).

Comment: @JeroenMostert That code compiles and runs well. I think I understand that it shouldn't, but I won't argue with compiler reality.

Comment: Well, as you haven't presented *all* the code, it's hard to tell what's going on, but I'm willing to bet some money that if you use "go to definition" in Visual Studio on the "different" values, you actually end up at the same spot. Otherwise, I'd be very interested to know what the type of `action` is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, enums are just ints (or long, or whatever number type you define). So, if you have multiple enums, casting them to int and comparing them can lead to the same value. However, that's why you don't cast them before comparing. This ensures type safety. If your two enums don't derive from the same type, your comparison would not even be possible, since you are expecting an enum value of type Class1._ACTION, but comparing it to an instance of Class2._Action. It should give you a compile time error. If the definition of your enum is part of a base class, then the instances would be the same and the dual comparison is redundant, as Jereon mentioned above.

Comment: This is the right answer, and after fixing the bug that led to my question, a compile time error appears just as predicted. Thank you, and thanks to @Jeroen Mostert.